# Locate the path of an Apache server on windows

Tags: windows, apache, batch-file, scripting

For a windows script I am writing, I need to detect if the machine has Apache 2.2 installed, and to find the application path.

One solution I came up with is to wget  http://localhost:8080/server-info and parse the root and the config file from it. This would fail if the server does not use port 8080

Another option would be to call “sc qc Apache2.2” and to parse the returning string. This would fail if the server is not installed as a service, or is using a different name.

Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a lot of great options if they didn't install it using the installer. If they used the MSI/installer, you can check the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Apache\2.2.2\ServerRoot 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Apache\2.2.2\ServerRoot
```

You can also check the running process list:

```
WMIC PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid
```

Look for the appropriate EXE. If for some reason you needed the port number, then use netstat and search for the appropriate port.

Also, when you say "a windows script", I am assuming you are using something modern and capable like [Windows Scripting Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(VS.85).aspx) (my favorite) or [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx). Don't even bother with batch files.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, Apache writes some registry keys.  If you know how to read them from a script, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

uvdesk

Unable to locate the path on the server.

Try putting index.php after your helpdesk installation's site url or If you are using apache, make sure that mode_rewrite module is enabled and AllowOverride directive for document root is set to All/FileInfo in your server's configuration file.`[enter code here][1]`

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to locate the path on the server.

A web server might don't have permission to allow overriding of the Apache config on a per-directory basis.

**Resolve Issue for windows:**

In **httpd.conf**, Allow Override needs to be set to All for the directory block as mentioned below:

```
<Directory /home/users/var/www/htdocs>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

**Resolve Issue for Linux:**

In **apache2.conf**, Allow Override needs to be set to All for the directory block as mentioned below:

```
<Directory /home/users/www>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

Also, Need to run below commands for **enabling mod rewrite rule**:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

**Then, restart web server:**

```
service apache2 restart
```

**Reference this solution for a better guide:**

https://github.com/uvdesk/community-skeleton/issues/143

https://github.com/uvdesk/community-skeleton/issues/155

Comment: Hi, please explain how your answer can help to solve the problem. Also, there is an already accepted answer, with very different content

Comment: Hello, this solution will be solve problem this error "Unable to locate the path on the server." in uvdesk project. Because this error due to mainly on web server don't have override permission so we have enabled in apache config file allow all overriding.

Comment: Ok, maybe these are valid configs, but they seems to be totally out of scope in reference to the question